How does position: sticky work within a flex DIV?
I read a lot about position: sticky in CSS. And I know, it does not work with overflow: hidden and display: flex. But I want to stick a button on top, that is positioned on the right of another element.
My sticky button is within another DIV to float on the right with another DIV on the left. But therefore position: sticky does not work.
Is there any other solution for this?


.top {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.body {
  background: grey;
}

.content {
  background: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.box {
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.box_left {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
}
<div class="top">
  This is the header.
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>
      This is a headline
    </h2>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box_left">
        Some information
      </div>
      <div class="sticky">
        This is a sticky button (does not work).
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="sticky">
      This is a sticky button (does work).
    </div>

<p>  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>



The sticky button does work if its not within the other DIV. But how can I place information left of the sticky button?


Could you put a runnable snippet into your question also I see from a comment that you want the element to stick to the top of the viewport (I think I've interpreted that correctly?) and so I assume when not stuck there you want it to be within the parent div and on its right hand side?

Hey @AHaworth, thank you. I added a running code snippet and a picture.

You can remove the box container and rely on float


.top {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.body {
  background: grey;
}

.content {
  background: white;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.box_left {
  background: green;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.sticky + * {
  clear: both;
}
<div class="top">
  This is the header.
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>
      This is a headline
    </h2>
      <div class="box_left">
        Some information
      </div>
      <div class="sticky">
        This is a sticky button (does not work).
      </div>
<p>  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>




Hey, thank you! That does really work. But there is one issue: If the left box is bigger than the right one, the text below does float around the boxes. But I want the text to appear below both boxes as a new line. You know what I mean? Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/qywtnuok/

@wepli23 you didn't copy all my code, there is a missing CSS I have used to clear float

Ah, you are right! Thank you! That does work!

Use can use Position:fixed instead of Position:sticky. I have changed Position to fixed and aligned it.
 .sticky {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 400px;
}


Thank you, that does work. But it is not the same as sticky. I would like the button to scroll with the content to the top and stick there.
